# D3js Updating path parse error will breaking path for while

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, data-visualization

I had use tree layout of d3.js for representing my chart. And the links are eblow type rectangular shape with rounded corner. the path attributes is like blow

```
 <path class="link" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);" marker-end="url(#arrowhead)" 
  marker-start="url(#markerCircle)" 
  d="M212,155H287.5a 3,3 0 0 1 3,3V197a 3,3 0 0 0 3,3H291.5V200H303">
```

path travel source to target. target are dynamic and movable so when I try to move target drag it at the same y - axis on source d3 trows error

```
Error: Problem parsing d="M212,155H288.5a 3,3 0 0 0.053023851851851767 3,-2.6818568888888894V145.863288a 3,3 0 0 0.9469761481481482 3,-2.6818568888888894H292.5V143.18143111111112H304" 

Error: Problem parsing d="M212,155H288.5a 3,3 0 0 0.015381185185185497 3,-2.907712888888887V143.83058400000002a 3,3 0 0 0.9846188148148145 3,-2.907712888888887H292.5V140.92287111111114H304"
```

and after some distance from y working well. I am setting arc radios always 3 but why it's take some float value on updating.

part of code which calculate path

arc function will will return arc

```
function getArc(_type,r,toDown){
                console.log(_type,r);
                var arc = "a "+r+","+r+" 0 0 0 "+r+","+r+"";
                var type = _type+"";
                switch (type){
                    case "1":
                        if(toDown){
                            arc = "a "+r+","+r+" 0 0 0 "+ ( -1*r ) +","+r+"";
                        }else{
                            arc = "a "+r+","+r+" 0 0 1 "+ r +","+( -1*r )+"";
                        }
                    break;
                    case "2":
                        arc = "a "+r+","+r+" 0 0 0 "+r+","+r+"";
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        arc = "a "+r+","+r+" 0 0 1 "+r+","+r+"";
                        break;
                    case "4":
                        if(toDown){
                            arc = "a "+r+","+r+" 0 0 1 "+ ( -1*r ) +","+r+"";
                        }else{
                            arc = "a "+r+","+r+" 0 0 0 "+ r +","+ ( -1*r)+"";
                        }
                        break;
                    default :
                        arc = "a "+r+","+r+" 0 0 0 "+r+","+r+"";
                }
                return arc;
            }
```

and the computed path function will create path

```
function getComputedPath(d){
                var _path = "";
                var x1,x2,y1,y2;
                x1 = d.source.x + d.source.width;
                y1 = d.source.y + (d.source.height/2);
                x2 = d.target.x;
                y2 = d.target.y;
                var _cx = (d.source_resource.x + d.source_resource.width + 15 + (getSidePadding(d.source_resource.id) *0.5)) - 3;
                 _path = "M"+x1+","+y1 + "H"+ _cx ;
                   var a1 = "",
                   a2 = "",
                   sp = 0;
                    if(Math.abs(y1-y2) > 3){
                      if(y1 < y2){
                        a1 = getArc(3,3,true);
                        a2 = getArc(2,3,true);
                        sp = 3;
                      }else{
                        a1 = getArc(4,3,false);
                        a2 = getArc(1,3,false);
                        sp = -3;
                      }
                    }
                    _path += a1 +"V"+ ( y2 - sp );
                    if(_cx > (x2-getSidePadding(d.target.id))){
                      _path += a2 +"H" + (_cx + Math.abs(sp) + 1);
                    }else{
                       _path += a2 +"H" + (x2-getSidePadding(d.target.id) + 4 );
                    }
                     _path += "V"+ y2 +"H"+ x2 ;
 }
```

Comment: Could you provide the code you use for this?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff : code had really too mess and many lines but I tried to provide example

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Please lookout for updated question......

Comment: Could you use one of the D3 path generators? That would make it much easier for you.

Comment: Which one gives me the path with rounded corner rectangular path ?

Comment: You could try e.g. basis interpolation.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff : what If I have array of points and want draw path from that point with step-before interpolate + rounded corner then any good hack for that?

Comment: You would have to write your own line generator.

Comment: That what I did above in my code !!!

Answer (score 1):

The format for an arc command is `"[A|a]rx,ry, x-axis-rotation, large-arc-flag, sweep-flag, x,y"` ([more info on path arcs](http://codepen.io/AmeliaBR/pen/kAIzf)).  Both the `large-arc-flag` and the `sweep-flag` represent boolean values, and have to be either 0 or 1.

The parse error is because you're switching from a counterclockwise sweep ( the fifth number of the arc command is 0) to a clockwise sweep (the fifth number is 1).  The default d3 transition for a string-based attribute -- like the `"d"` attribute of a path -- calculates intermediate values for *every* number in your string.  But intermediate values aren't valid in this context, causing the errors.

So you have two choices:  either get rid of the transition, or create a custom tween function that calculates your path at each position with correct syntax.

Comment: any idea how can I override tween function for calculate path ?

Comment: [This example on using custom tweens for `d3.svg.arc` shapes](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5100636) might be a better starting point.  You can also search SO, I've written a couple discussions on custom tweens.  For your code, you probably want to modify your "getArc" code so that you can specify the angle of the arc, and then  transition the angle.